# Make object shoot - Pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Im new to python and for my course at university we have been set the task of creating a game using pygame, I obtained help from some Youtube tutorials and this is the code I have so far:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
background = pygame.image.load('grassy.gif')
turret = pygame.image.load('turret.png').convert_alpha()
pygame.display.set_caption("Tank Blast!")
moveX, moveY = 0,0

class Turret:

 def __init__ (self, x, y):

    self.x=x
    self.y=y
    self.width=50
    self.height=50
    self.i0 = pygame.image.load("turret.png")
    self.i1 = pygame.image.load("turret2.png")
    self.timeTarget = 10
    self.timeNum = 0
    self.currentImage = 0

def update (self):

    self.timeNum+=1

    if (self.timeNum==self.timeTarget):

        if (self.currentImage==0):

            self.currentImage+=1

        else:

            self.currentImage=0

        self.timeNum=0

    self.render()

def render(self):

    if (self.currentImage==0):

        window.blit(self.i0, (self.x, self.y))

    else:

        window.blit(self.i1, (self.x, self.y))

player = Turret(380, 480)
while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):

        sys.exit()

    if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):

        if (event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):

            moveX = -7

        if (event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):

            moveX = 7

    if (event.type==pygame.KEYUP):

        if (event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):

            moveX = 0

        if (event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):

            moveX = 0


window.blit(background, (0,0))

player.x+=moveX

player.y+=moveY

player.update()

pygame.display.flip()

clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

My question is, what would I have to do to make the turret shoot bullets by pressing the space bar?
If anyone can help me Id appreciate it a lot,

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should create a `Bullet` class. When the `Turret` shoots it creates a new `Bullet` object that will probably have a method to `move` and another method like `destroy` where it will check whether it is colliding with something and then destroy itself and that object. Also, your `Bullet` class should inherit from `pygame.sprite.Sprite` as follows:

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        ...
    ...
```

That way when you create a lot of bullets you can group them together into `pygame.sprite.Group`. For example, if you create a `pygame.sprite.Group` called `bullets` to which you added all your bullet instances you can then `update` all the bullets by calling:

`bullets.update() #this will then call the update() method of the individual bullets`

I suggest you read about `pygame.sprite.Sprite` and `pygame.sprite.Group`.

They are really handy when dealing with multiple instances of similar objects.

Note: I'd recommend using `pygame.display.update()` instead of `pygame.display.flip()`. It is a better way of doing it.

Happy Pygaming!